# how to select convert list varchar for WHERE IN() SQL Query

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures

how to select convert list varchar for 
WHERE IN() SQL Query

```
 select code from table1 
 Code
 10223
 10240
 10047
 10174
 10187
 10192
 10212
 10213
 10195


  select * table2 from where code in 
  ('10047','10174','10187','10192','10212','10213','10195')
```

I Need stored-procedures for this

Comment: Do you mean that in table1 the codes are numeric, and in table2 the codes are the same but of type varchar?

Comment: varchar only string @Mureinik

Comment: Your comment "varchar only string" doesn't help at all, please tell us which type the code fields of each table have.

Comment: Both are Varchar @martinstoeckli

Comment: So there is no need for a conversion, the solution of Mureinik should work.

Comment: ..............IN (SELECT code FROM table1)

Comment: No i Need like list
Select code from table1
Select * from table2 where code  IN ('10047','10174','10187','10192','10212','10213','10195')

If its numeric it will work but it is varchar @martinstoeckli

Comment: IF int means
select * from table where code IN (1,2,3,4)
IF varchar
select * from table where code IN ('1','2','3','4')

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @Thank YOU @@martinstoeckli I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator can operate on a query, so there's no need for such a conversion:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table2
WHERE  code IN (SELECT code FROM table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives:

### Use Join:

Assuming the `Code` column in `table1` is unique:

```
SELECT t2.* FROM table2 t2 INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON CAST(t1.code AS VARCHAR)=CAST(t2.code AS VARCHAR)
```

### Inner Query

```
SELECT * FROM  table2 WHERE code IN 
(SELECT code FROM table1)
```

Comment: Those two statements won't necessarily return the same thing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you are right, I've edited the answer